# Change/Set password for git system account on omnibus gitlab server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, gitlab, passwd, gitlab-omnibus

We installed gitlab in **omnibus** method.We are using g**itlab-rake console** for lot of our administration activity.If it is a one time activity we can get root access and do our activity as **sudo**.In case of permanent scheduled operation we are facing problem with root access.

**As per company policy no one can have permanent root access.**

We know we can run gitlab-rake console via git system user but in omnibus method git account is password less.

```
[root@host:/etc]# grep git /etc/shadow
git:!!:16904::::::
gitlab-www:!!:16904::::::
gitlab-redis:!!:16904::::::
gitlab-psql:!!:16904::::::
```

if we set password to git or gitlab-www or gitlab-psql , we were able to login as that account and able to proceed with the show.

But my issue is what could be the impact on gitlab if we change/set password to this account.

Will it impact gitlab infrastructure?
Will it create any problem?
Will it affect the gitlab performance?
Will it affect the gitlab functionality?

Please help us.